# Hosting Media files when Django DEBUG = False

Tags: django, django-templates, apache2

I'm getting a little issue in order to serve `Media files` in my webserver. 
My web application is in **production mode**, so I have to set `DEBUG = false`.

**This is my project :**

```
Astrophotographie
|
|_ Accueil
|_ Articles
|_ Astrophotographie
|_ Astro_Database
|_ manage.py
|_ Media
|     |_ Media
|          |_ list of pictures
|_ static
|_ templates
|_ virtualenv
```

**My settings.py file :**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
THEME_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), THEME_DIRS, ]

MEDIA_URL = "/Media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Media")
```

Well, it's done and I know that Django can't host Media files like this, so I have `Apache2` in order to do that. I configured Apache2, so all my website sounds like, but I don't overcome to display pictures.

**Apache2 config :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    Alias /Media/  /home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie/Media
    Alias /static/ /home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie/staticfiles

    <Directory /home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie/Media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie/Astrophotographie>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess astro/Astrophotographie python-path=/home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie python-home=/home/pi/astro/astroenv
    WSGIProcessGroup astro/Astrophotographie
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie/Astrophotographie/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Alias seems to be good right ?
I miss something in my configuration in order to display pictures correctly ?

This is what I get on my website :

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Both your Django and Apache settings are unreadable; copy and paste them here as actual text.

Comment: I'm working with SSH so I have to write all things or take a screen capture :/ I will try to make it better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer, I had to modify my apache2 file like this :

```
Alias /Media/  /home/pi/astro/Astrophotographie/Media/
```

I forgot the `/` at the end of my line. Now, with `DEBUG = False`, it works fine